# Mongoose - Multiple Schemas vs Objects within One Schema to store connected documents

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have `MemberSchema` and `FacebookSchema` in my Mongo Database.

If the member registers to my website, the member info will be stored in `MemberSchema`.

If the registered member want to connect with his facebook account, he needs to authenticate his facebook account to my website. Then, all his facebook account information will be stored in `FacebookSchema`.

That's my current Schema configuration:

```
var Member = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    memberType: { type: String , default: 'webaccount' },
    facebookAccount: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'facebook_accounts' }
});

var FacebookAccount = new Schema({
    fbId: String,
    email: { type : String , lowercase : true},
    name: String,
    memberType: { type: String , default: 'facebook' }
});
```

The two schemas are connected via `facebookAcount` property of `MemberSchema`.

But I've considered another way of storing these data by `Object` type in Schema.

```
var Member = mongoose.Schema({

    webaccount            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }
});
```

From you opinion, which might be the better way to apply in this situation?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should nest facebook data into the member collection. 
MongoDB is not suitable to execute joins.